# Do the tickets expire?

Tags: mario-kart-tour

Do I have to use any ticket (level-boost, quick, star, etc) before the end of the cup?

Or do the tickets have no expiring date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the cup ended and the tickets did not expire.